# PHP regex doesn't work at real server

Tags: php, regex

I have regex for detecting Cyrillic First, Middle and Last names.

```
([А-Я][а-я]+\s+[А-Я][а-я]+[.|\s|][А-Я][а-я]+[.|\s|])
```

Using:

```
preg_match_all('/([А-Я][а-я]+(\\s|.|[ ])[А-Я][а-я]+(\\s|.|[ ])[А-Я][а-я]+)/','it\'s a test string with a name like Васильців Василь Васильович and Петро Петрович Петренко смисми ВВ Аммм Мммм Аааааа',$ar);
```

The results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => �асил�
            [1] => �асил�
            [2] => �асильови�
            [3] => енко
            [4] => мисми
            [5] => �ааааа
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => �асил�
            [1] => �асил�
            [2] => �асильови�
            [3] => енко
            [4] => мисми
            [5] => �ааааа
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => �
            [1] => �
            [2] => �
            [3] => �
            [4] => �
            [5] => �
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => �
            [1] => �
            [2] => �
            [3] => �
            [4] => �
            [5] => �
        )

)
```

It's working fine at https://regex101.com/r/xA6vX0/1 but does not work in PHP (it's detecting wrong text parts).
Can you explain what's wrong or prompt me to a better online service?

Comment: Check if adding `u` helps: `'/([А-Я][а-я]+(\\s|.|[ ])[А-Я][а-я]+(\\s|.|[ ])[А-Я][а-я]+)/u'`

Comment: Have you tried with unicode escaping \uXXXX? http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just [tested on PHP v.5.5.18](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMU2V0VllpaUtzRkE) - `u` option works well:

```
preg_match_all('/([А-ЯЁ][ёа-я]+(?:[\\s.][ЁА-Я][ёа-я]+){2})/u','it\'s a test string with a name like Васильців Василь Васильович and Петро Петрович Петренко смисми ВВ Аммм Мммм Аааааа',$ar);
print_r($ar);
```

Also, I contracted the spaces part with a period that was unescaped, and the pattern itself.

Output:

```
Array                                                                                                                                                                
(                                                                                                                                                                    
    [0] => Array                                                                                                                                                     
        (                                                                                                                                                            
            [0] => Петро Петрович Петренко                                                                                                                           
            [1] => Аммм Мммм Аааааа                                                                                                                                  
        )                                                                                                                                                            

    [1] => Array                                                                                                                                                     
        (                                                                                                                                                            
            [0] => Петро Петрович Петренко                                                                                                                           
            [1] => Аммм Мммм Аааааа                                                                                                                                  
        )                                                                                                                                                            

)
```

Comment: There is one more catch: if you want to also capture the letter `ё`, you will need to add it as a separate character to the range. Sorry, forgot about it in the beginning, adding it now. (Also, please consider upvoting if the answer proved useful to you).